# logging.raiseExceptions = True does not re-raise an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am trying to have the following functionality in my code:

- Log info and error messages and also exceptions to console and/or a file, without interrupting the program flow (i.e., swallowing exceptions, some kind of **Run Mode**)
- Get into **Development Mode**, where exceptions are raised, by setting a `develop = True` flag

Currently, I am using the Python3 `logging` module, which (according to [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html#exceptions-raised-during-logging)) should have exactly that functionality built-in. The flag is then `logging.raiseExceptions = True`.

However, I am not getting this to work in a MWE: the exception I am throwing does not get re-raised, whatever my setting of the flag is.

```
# mwe.py
import logging
import logging.config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Configure logging and set flag to raise exceptions
    logging.config.fileConfig('log.conf')
    logging.raiseExceptions = True

    logger = logging.getLogger('root')

    logger.info('Started')

    # Test whether exceptions get raised
    try:
        raise RuntimeError("Ooops.")
    except RuntimeError:
        try:
            logger.exception('There was an oops.')
            # which is the same as logger.error('...', exc_info=True)
        except:
            print("GOTCHA! Exception was re-raised.")

    logger.info('Finished')
```

The corresponding **config file**:

```
# log.conf
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter

[logger_root]
handlers=consoleHandler
level=DEBUG

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=logging.StreamHandler
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(filename)s (%(lineno)d) %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s
```

This produces the following **output**:

```
mwe.py (12) INFO     - Started
mwe.py (19) ERROR    - There was an oops.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mwe.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Ooops.")
RuntimeError: Ooops.
mwe.py (24) INFO     - Finished
```

---

Why am I not getting to the `GOTCHA` part, although the default value of `raiseExceptions` is `True` and additionally I am also setting it to `True`? What is wrong with my configuration?
Or do I have some big misunderstanding about the use of `logging` for this purpose?

(Little bonus question: is there a way to configure the `raiseException` flag in the `log.conf` file?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got it wrong. This will not re-raise any custom exception. This is meant to change the default behaviour of logging module which is swallowing **internal** logging exceptions i.e. misconfigured logger trying to write to a file where it has no permissions to write. This will fail silently by default and setting `logging.raiseException = True` will cause logger misconfiguration or any other problem **within** logging module to raise an exception which you would have to handle.

Now to the point of what you are trying to achieve. Having an exception traceback logged without suppressing the exception (letting it propagate) is the default behaviour. If logging is not configured the traceback goes to stderr. If logging is configured, it's written by logging handler to the desired location.
So basically in order to achieve your goal, you should not handle the exception at all. However if you know how to handle the exception (meaning you know what causes the exception) then normally you don't need a traceback to be logged.
If you insist you can still use `logger.exception(...)` inside your `except RuntimeError` clause and re-raise the exception with pure `raise`:

```
try:
    raise RuntimeError("Ooops.")
except RuntimeError:
    logger.exception('There was an oops.')
    raise
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification! What would be the best practice here for custom exceptions and if I want the possibility of the program not stopping when they are raised (e.g. due to some bad input data)? Should I not raise any custom exceptions in the first place but just log the error; or should I raise the custom exceptions and then automatically handle them (e.g. by `sys.excepthook`) ... I am a bit confused here. :/

Comment: Just use `try...except` without re-raising it inside except block. Having custom exceptions is fine.